# Отправить форму без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery

хотел бы узнать, как можно отправить форму не перезагружая загружая страницу, желательно БЕЗ АЯКСА.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<form action="/action_page.php" method="get">
  TEST
  <br/>
  <button type="submit">Normal Submit</button>
  <button type="submit" formtarget="myframe">Submit to a frame</button>
</form>

<br/>
<iframe name="myframe" src="about:blank"></iframe>
```

Comment: Дело в том, что мне не нужно, что бы все сабмит-кнопки вели в другое место, а только одна определенная

Answer (score 0):

Если не хотите AJAX, отправьте тогда get или post запрос) вот вам пример кода

```
var cform = $( "#client-request-form" ),
        cResponse = $( '<div class="cf_response"></div>'),
        cInputs = $( '.cf_form_inputs_block' ),
        cLoader = $( '.form-loader' );
    cform.prepend(cResponse);
    /*cform.h5Validate();*/

    cform.submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        /*if(cform.h5Validate('allValid')) {*/
            cResponse.hide();
            cLoader.show();
            $.post(
                $(this).attr('action'),
                cform.serialize(),
                function(data){
                    cLoader.hide();
                    cResponse.html(data).fadeIn('fast');
                    cInputs.fadeOut('fast');
                    if(data.match('success') != null) {
                        cform.get(0).reset();
                    }
                }
            ); // end post
        /*}
        return false;*/
    });
```